# How to find the number of unique values in vector for each values from another vetor

Tags: r, aggregate, data.table, apply

I have two vectors:

```
x <- c(1,5,3,2,3, 4,1,2,3,4, 10,5,2,10,12)
y <- c(1,1,2,2,2, 3,3,1,4,4, 4,5,5,4,4)
```

How can I find the number of unique numbers from X for each number from Y?

I know how to find the number of non-unique numbers from X for each number from Y:

```
r=aggregate(x ~ y , data= data, FUN=length)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`, this is pretty easy:

```
require(data.table)
DT = data.table(x,y)
unique(DT, by=c("x", "y"))[, .N, by=y]
#    y N
# 1: 1 3
# 2: 2 2
# 3: 3 2
# 4: 4 4
# 5: 5 2
```

Comment: A little bit different question: how can I find number of 1s, 2s from vector x for each value from y?

Comment: @user45415631 `DT[, .N, keyby = list(y, x)]`?; Arun - what's the point of specifying `by` in that `unique`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it wih `dplyr` this way :

```
data.frame(x,y) %>% 
    group_by(y) %>% 
    summarize(nb=length(unique(x)))
```

Which gives :

```
  y nb
1 1  3
2 2  2
3 3  2
4 4  4
5 5  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
rowSums(!!table(y,x))
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 3 2 2 4 2
```